# How to retain execute permission on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Title says it all really, I want to retain the permissions that I set. Currently I have to re-grant my execute privelages Every single morning using the following command:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON myDbName.* TO 'myUid'@'localhost';
```

My Google Cloud SQL instance serves data to my Google AppEngine application, whithout the EXECUTE permission my AppEngine app reports a 500 error to my users, once the above GRANT has been run the AppEngine app continues to work all day but by the next morning my AppEngine app stops working and reports:

```
(1370, "execute command denied to user 'myUid'@'localhost' for routine 'myDbName.sp_my_proc'")
```

I re-run the grant and it works again. My AppEngine app has no cron.yaml so I know that there are no overnight/periodical jobs running which could be Revoking this permission.

I am in GMT (London) timezone if that makes any difference? I only mention it as I know the AppEngine quota's reset early in the morning here.

Also worth noting this user has other permissions (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE) in the database which are Not lost overnight, just EXECUTE.

Has anyone else had this issue? Or got any suggestions for how to debug/fix?

Comment: Today I ran the SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myUid'@'localhost' SQL command, before and after running my EXECUTE command, the results are identical both before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after doing the GRANT's fixed this for me.